# Creating a SELECT and JOIN after a UNION

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a UNION beetween to tables that looks like this:

```
SELECT GetStudentClassmates.AvatarFileName  as AvatarFileName,
       GetStudentClassmates.UserName        as UserName,
       GetStudentClassmates.RoleId          as RoleId
FROM GetStudentClassmates
WHERE GetStudentClassmates.StudentId = @studentId

UNION

SELECT GetStudentTeachers.AvatarFileName    as AvatarFileName,
       GetStudentTeachers.UserName          as UserName,
       GetStudentTeachers.RoleId            as RoleId
FROM GetStudentTeachers
```

Now I need to join the result of the UNION with to other tables and add another column to the final result.

This is the JOIN code I am using

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sync_StudentAssignments as StudentAssignments 
  ON @studentId = StudentAssignments.StudentID 
  AND StudentAssignments.Deletion_Date IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sync_StudentAssignmentInstances as StudentAssignmentInstances 
  ON StudentAssignments.StudentAssignmentID = StudentAssignmentInstances.StudentAssignmentID 
  AND StudentAssignmentInstances.Deletion_Date IS NULL
```

My problem is that I do not know where I have to add the select code , that would look something like this I think:

```
SELECT StudentAssignmentInstances.ModuleInstanceId
```

My final table should have the following columns:

```
AvatarFileName,
UserName,
RoleId,
ModuleInstanceId
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the relationship between the union and the two joined tables?

Comment: Your UNION means following: _get me one student and all of the teachers in the same recordset_; Was that really what you wanted?

Comment: yes the data that I am getting will be used in the same place and the RoleID will be use to diferentiate beetween roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server If you want to join with some union you can use subselect form or CTE.
Here I would use CTE because it adds some order in TSQL code...

```
;WITH Participants AS (
  SELECT GetStudentClassmates.AvatarFileName  as AvatarFileName,
         GetStudentClassmates.UserName        as UserName,
         GetStudentClassmates.RoleId          as RoleId
  FROM GetStudentClassmates
  WHERE GetStudentClassmates.StudentId = @studentId

  UNION ALL

  SELECT GetStudentTeachers.AvatarFileName    as AvatarFileName,
         GetStudentTeachers.UserName          as UserName,
         GetStudentTeachers.RoleId            as RoleId
  FROM GetStudentTeachers)
SELECT
FROM 
  Participants p
  JOIN WhateverYouWant wyw
    ON wyw.{column1} = p.{column1}
    AND wyw.{column2} = p.{column2}
    ...
```

Here `WhateverYouWant` is probably your `Sync_StudentAssignments JOIN Sync_StudentAssignmentInstances`. However, you have joined that using a variable and a const, which would give a cartesian product and I believe that was not your intention.

**EDIT**

Now I was looking at your conditions more carefully, I believe you have to do the following:

```
;WITH Participants AS (
  SELECT GetStudentClassmates.AvatarFileName,
         GetStudentClassmates.UserName,
         GetStudentClassmates.RoleId,
         GetStudentClassmates.StudentId       
  FROM GetStudentClassmates
  --WHERE GetStudentClassmates.StudentId = @studentId
  --uncomment previous line only if you need just one student in your recordset

  UNION ALL

  SELECT GetStudentTeachers.AvatarFileName,
         GetStudentTeachers.UserName,
         GetStudentTeachers.RoleId,
         GetStudentClassmates.TeacherId AS StudentId -- just guessing column name
  FROM GetStudentTeachers
  --previous select means you need all of the teachers, no matter which student
)
SELECT
  p.AvatarFileName,
  p.UserName,
  p.RoleId,
  StudentAssignmentInstances.ModuleInstanceId
FROM 
  Participants p
  LEFT JOIN Sync_StudentAssignments as StudentAssignments 
    ON p.StudentId = StudentAssignments.StudentID 
    AND StudentAssignments.Deletion_Date IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN Sync_StudentAssignmentInstances as StudentAssignmentInstances 
    ON StudentAssignments.StudentAssignmentID = StudentAssignmentInstances.StudentAssignmentID 
    AND StudentAssignmentInstances.Deletion_Date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your `UNION` bit in brackets and use it as an in-line table, then join normally:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
-- choose the exact columns you need here using the aliases
-----------------------------------------------------------
select x.*, ssa.*, ssai.* from
(
   select ....
   union
   select ....
) as x
inner join Sync_StudentAssignments ssa on ...
inner join Sync_StudentAssignmentInstances ssai on ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbl.AvartarFileName, 
       tbl.UserName, 
       tbl.RoleId, 
       StudentAssignmentInstances.ModuleInstanceId
FROM
(
    SELECT GetStudentClassmates.AvatarFileName  as AvatarFileName,
           GetStudentClassmates.UserName        as UserName,
           GetStudentClassmates.RoleId          as RoleId
      FROM GetStudentClassmates
     WHERE GetStudentClassmates.StudentId = @studentId

     UNION

    SELECT GetStudentTeachers.AvatarFileName    as AvatarFileName,
           GetStudentTeachers.UserName          as UserName,
           GetStudentTeachers.RoleId            as RoleId
           FROM GetStudentTeachers
) AS tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sync_StudentAssignments as StudentAssignments 
  ON @studentId = StudentAssignments.StudentID 
  AND StudentAssignments.Deletion_Date IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sync_StudentAssignmentInstances as StudentAssignmentInstances 
  ON StudentAssignments.StudentAssignmentID = StudentAssignmentInstances.StudentAssignmentID 
  AND StudentAssignmentInstances.Deletion_Date IS NULL
```